# Replace selected text and keep HTML inside selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, replace

is it possible to replace selected text and keep HTML (span inside selected text)?

I would like to make text Upper or Lower on button click and keep html tag span inside selected text. My code looks like this.

```js
function replaceSelectedText(replacementText) {
    var sel, range;
    var selectedText=window.getSelection().toString();
  // Pokud je oznaceny text a je obsazen v divu 'zprava'
    if ($.trim(selectedText)!="") {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();
                range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.text = replacementText;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable>DJSH SAJKDH ASDK ahsjkda sdasd <span style="color:red">asjda lsdjkl LASJD ASLdkja sdlASdjk aůskjd aůSdkj asdů</span></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="replaceSelectedText(window.getSelection().toString().toLowerCase());">a&#8595;</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="replaceSelectedText(window.getSelection().toString().toUpperCase());">A&#8593;</button>
```

Comment: Try using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: why not just css "text-transform:uppercase" on click toggle a class to the text and apply the css

Comment: It is absolutely possible, You need to edit the text nodes. Using CSS is probably a better and easier solution though.

Comment: CSS is not possible, because user could want to replace only part of text

Comment: So you will have to get the text node content, and use your values from `range` to `String#slice` the string and concatenate the capitalised content where it needs to be. Then write the string back to the text nodes.

Comment: Could you please show me a bit of code?

Comment: This is not a simple task and not something that I have time for right now I'm afraid. You may find some code/library that is already written for this problem. I don't know of one off the top of my head, perhaps someone else does,